# Wrong Y axis when drawing on canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw on a canvas but the Y axis appears to be wrong. It looks like 0 is actually -100.

For example, when I draw a red square that is 10 px from every border I get the following square:

[image]

The code I am using:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRect(10, 10, canvas.getWidth() - 10, canvas.getHeight() - 10, paint);
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:background="@color/facebook_color"
                android:id="@+id/catchImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />

            <View
                android:background="@color/news_item_seperator_stroke"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I use the following code everything works fine:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);

Paint paint2 = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint2);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0vvb.png

Comment: Your second code appears to work, because it makes no difference to that code that some of the canvas is not on screen.

Comment: When I draw a rectangle on 0,110,height-110,width It fills the whole screen except the borders of 10 px. What could cause it that I have to add 100?

Comment: If your screen is e.g. 800 x 600, your canvas seems to be 1000 x 600. This is due to your broken layout. Fix your layout, and you fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, your canvas is just bigger than the current screen. Check your layout xml. Remember: The coordinates are relative to the canvas and not relative to the visible part of it.

Comment: But I also save the bitmap and there I have the same problem. http://i.imgur.com/Z5PYx89.jpg The bitmap that I save is the same I see on the screen so the canvas isn't bigger than the screen, right?

Comment: Can you provide the layout?

Comment: I added the layout to the original question

Comment: Try to set the `layout_height` of the ImageView to 200dp (just for test purposes).

Comment: And your inner LinearLayout is vertical with two elements of width `match_parent`. That doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I'm going to add more items to the layout.

Comment: No, I changed the height but because the ImageView has the scaletype fitcenter it shows an empty space on the left and right. (The imageview background is blue)

Answer (score 0):

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

You are generating the canvas from a bitmap, this means the Bitmap can be of any size and not exactly of the view.

You should get the width/heigh from the View with getWidth() and getHeight()

Comment: What you are suggesting is that 3rd and 4th params are width and height of the rectangle to draw, i.e. relative to the first two params, but that is not true, they are absolute: [drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Comment: Oh.. true, i was thinking ltrb but still tought that was correct. The PS part is kind wrong